# How to create navbar with "drawer-looking" behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create "drawer-looking" navbar inspired by this IKEA's :[IKEA navbar](http://www.ikea.com/aa/en/). When clicking on "Rooms" I expected not only appearing the list of rooms but also wanted to slide down the rest of the page content.I've used JQuery animate() but it doesn't work.I'm aware of course that I need to synchronise somehow list toggling and my green div (aka "page content")behaviour but first I have to force the green div to move down when I click on "Rooms".How to do it ?

[Link to my Pen on Codepen](http://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/rzjbLP)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".headers:first").on({
    click: function() {
      $(".rooms").slideToggle();
      /*  $("#restof").slideToggle();*/
      /* $("#restof").css("padding-top","300px").slideToggle();
       */
      $("#restof").animate({
        top: "100px"
      });
    },
  });
});
```

```css
#restof {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.rooms {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.headers {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


/*
.movedown{
  margin-top:100px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="headers" id="rooms">Rooms</li>
    <ul class="rooms">
      <li>BEDROOM</li>
      <li>KITCHEN</li>
      <li>BATHROOM</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="headers" id="products">Products</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="restof" </div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdNVrp - Have your primary navigation first, then your secondary navigations. Remove `position:absolute` and the content will move by itself. Done.

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect; the child `ul` must be placed within a `li`. It cannot be a child of another `ul`. You're also missing a `>` on the `div`, and have an extra `,` in the JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` for the submenu and put the submenu in the end of the nav in html code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".headers:first").on({
    click: function() {
      $(".rooms").slideToggle();
      /*  $("#restof").slideToggle();*/
      /* $("#restof").css("padding-top","300px").slideToggle();
       */
      $("#restof").animate({
        top: "100px"
      });
    },
  });
});
```

```css
#restof {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.rooms {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.headers {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


/*
.movedown{
  margin-top:100px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="headers" id="rooms">Rooms</li>
    <li class="headers" id="products">Products</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="rooms">
      <li>BEDROOM</li>
      <li>KITCHEN</li>
      <li>BATHROOM</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="restof" </div>
```